# Seleccionar cualquier hijo de un elemento css

Tags: css, css3

¿Existe la posibilidad de seleccionar todos los hijos de un determinado elemento, a pesar de que estos sean diferentes? Pongo un código de ejemplo;

```
<div id='contenedor'>
    <a href='#'>Esto es un ejemplo>
    <h1>Ejemplo h1</h1>
    <p>Parrafo de ejemplo</p>
</div>
```

Me refiero a poder dar estilos a todos los elementos dentro del `div id='contenedor'` en un sola declaración. Por ejemplo, que los elementos `a`, `h1` y `p` tengan un margen de 20px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puede usar `*` justo despues de su selector padre para aplicar estilo a sus hijos así:

```
#contenedor * {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Vaya era muy sencillo, sólo tenía que pensar un poquito más. Gracias

Comment: No hay problema =)

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de expresar exactamente lo que quieres es:

```
foobar > * {}
```

El estilo anterior seleccionará todo elemento hijo de `foobar`.

Si tu intención es seleccionar todo elemento hijo de `foo`, `bar` y `baz`, sería:

```
foo, bar, baz > * {}
```

Comment: Hola ortizlab, la pregunta es bastante vieja. En todo caso, el último caso que propones debería ser foo > *, bar > *, baz > * {}. Si no, sólo se seleccionarán los elementos foo, bar y los hijos de baz. Saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises `foo, bar, baz > * {}`, puesto que todo elemento dentro de, tanto `foo`, como `bar` y `baz`, heredan el estilo. Te dejo un enlace con más información al respecto, para que puedas resolver las dudas que tengas respecto a esta pregunta. [How to select all child elements recursively using CSS?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-select-all-child-elements-recursively-using-css/)

Comment: https://codepen.io/xxx41/pen/dEWvEo

Comment: A lo mejor no funciona bien Codepen, prueba en about:blank. [Ejemplo](https://i.imgur.com/4NsTfuW.png)

Comment: Eso ocurre porque la propiedad color afecta a los hijos del contenedor. Te dejo otro ejemplo para que lo puedas probar. https://codepen.io/xxx41/pen/dERZRV